# How can I useRef with HTMLInputElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Working with React and hooks:**

I have this `ParentCompontent` which contains its own logic and content which rerenders when its `props.otherStuff` changes (as usual). 
But I also have a special made `InputComponent`. The `InputComponent` renders a JSX.Element with an `<input>` with some basic attributes. One attribute is `ref` which is a function that returns the HTMLInputElement to the prop `onSetInputRef`.
The only thing you need to know is that whichever function I place in the prop `onSetInputRef` gives me the `HTMLInputElement` as an argument so I can access it in the parent component.

How can i use my useRef and "set" it as the HTMLInputElement. Is there a way?
Also if that is possible. When `props.otherStuff` changes I still want to focus on that input element. Anyone that can help me? Im not that good with ref..

So here is what i've tried:

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {

   const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        inputRef.focus()
    }, [props.otherStuff]);

   const setRef = (inputElement: <HTMLInputElement>) => {
    inputRef = inputElement;
   }

return (
    <>
        <>
         {render props.otherStuff}
        </>
        <InputComponent
         ...otherProps
         onSetInputRef={setRef}
       />
     </>
    )
 }
```

Comment: Do the react [`uesRef` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) help at all?

Comment: Well. I was a bit confused with a setRef function. But yea. Still find ref a bit confusing with it being able to be an integer, function etc etc. Need to study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `current` property of your ref:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  inputRef.current.focus()
}, [props.otherStuff]);

const setRef = (inputElement: HTMLInputElement) => {
  inputRef.current = inputElement;
}
```

I hope this helps.